# Is the server bundled with Flask safe to use in production?

Tags: python, flask, werkzeug

Is the server bundled with Flask safe for deployment in a production environment? If not, what should I use to deploy Flask in production?

Comment: This [answer](https://www.reddit.com/r/Python/comments/8bb102/why_shouldnt_one_use_flask_bottle_django_etc/dx5qklz/) gives a wider context to this problem, and explains why using the server bundled with Flask should not be used.

Answer (score 147):

**No**. The bundled server is a *development* server. It's not designed with production environments in mind.

- It will not handle more than one request at a time by default.
- If you leave debug mode on and an error pops up, it opens up a shell that allows for arbitrary code to be executed on your server (think `os.system('rm -rf /')`).
- The development server doesn't scale well.

Flask uses Werkzeug's development server, and the documentation says the same thing:

> The development server is not intended to be used on production systems. It was designed especially for development purposes and performs poorly under high load. For deployment setups have a look at the [Application Deployment](http://werkzeug.pocoo.org/docs/0.14/deployment/) pages.

The recommended approach is to [use a production WSGI server](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/1.0/deploying/wsgi-standalone/) to run your Flask application. There's a whole section dedicated to deployment in the docs: [Deployment Options](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/deploying/).

Deploying your application is as simple as installing a WSGI server like uWSGI or gunicorn and running that instead of Flask's development server:

```
gunicorn -w 4 -b 127.0.0.1:4000 myproject:app
```

---

If you are serving any static assets like images or videos, need low-level caching, or have higher concurrency demands, it's recommended to use a webserver like [nginx](http://nginx.org/) and have it handle all of your requests.

In crappy ASCII form:

```
                +----------+
                | Client 2 |
                +----------+
                      |
                      V 
+----------+      +-------+      +----------+
| Client 1 |----->| nginx |<-----| Client 3 |
+----------+      +-------+      +----------+
                      ^
                      |
                      V
           /--------------------\
           | useful nginx stuff |
           | like asset serving |
           | and rate limiting  |
           \--------------------/
                      |
                      V
               +-------------+
               | WSGI server |
               +-------------+
```

To actually *run* the WSGI server process, you can use [Supervisor](http://supervisord.org/). It automatically restarts the server if it fails for some reason, keeps logs, and runs as a daemon so your service starts when the server boots.

Comment: I use `supervisor` + `gunicorn` + `nginx`. It is really easy to setup and maintain.

Comment: "It will not handle more than one request at a time" - not true, see threaded and processes arguments : http://werkzeug.pocoo.org/docs/0.11/serving/

Comment: "if an error pops up, it opens up a shell that allows for arbitrary code to be executed on your server" - isn't that debug=True mode ?

Comment: @HaveAGuess: Amended. By default, though, the server will not be multithreaded. Those arguments aren't mentioned anywhere in the Flask docs, so you have to look at Werkzeug's documentation, which I think is more work than most people will do.

Comment: @HaveAGuess: From the flask deployment [doc](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.11/deploying/): "Flask’s built-in server is not suitable for production as it doesn’t scale well and **by default serves only one request at a time.**"

Comment: @mvarge agreed but we had it scaled up to multiprocesses with *no problems* to handle multiple requests for an internal production app. We are now running on Apache for external exposure

Comment: @Blender Sorry to disturb you. I'm writing a post about Werkzeug, and I have some silly questions. Is the server provided by Werkzeug similar to Gunicorn in functionality? Can I call it "WSGI server"?

Comment: @GreyLi: Yeah, both are WSGI servers. That's why you can swap out the dev server for a production server without any code modifications.

Comment: 1) "It will not handle more than one request at a time by default" => can be changed with `threaded` option. 
2) "If you leave debug mode on and an error pops up, it opens up a shell that allows for arbitrary code to be executed" => this could be easily turned off with a few lines of code.  3) "The development server doesn't scale well." => a benchmark (if someone has one) would be interesting to add concrete facts to help people understand why the bundled server is really so bad. I trust you, but everyone [seems](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12269604/1422096)  to repeat this without source.

Comment: @Basj: I would consider the people who *wrote* the development server to be a canonical source. General-purpose deployment guidelines try to address the common use case, which is deploying a public webservice. Can you get away with using the development server for a low-traffic webservice? Sure, but why waste the effort trying to make the development server into an almost-production server when `pip install uwsgi && uwsgi --http :8000 -w yourapp:app` works just as well and is actually tailored for that use case?

Comment: @Haveaguess link is down for me but for the WSGi serving options see here: https://werkzeug.palletsprojects.com/en/1.0.x/serving/.    

Another alternative to using the development server is to run the Flask app as a service with systemd, nginx proxy and gunicorn: https://edmondchuc.com/deploying-python-flask-with-gunicorn-nginx-and-systemd/

Comment: @Blender I do not understand what is yourapp:app there. I start flask server by running: python patch_to_file_with_flask_server.py

Answer (score 21):

Basically, no. The built-in development server is not safe for deployment in a production environment.

The built in *development* server is for just that. For use in production you should follow one of the steps detailed [here](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/deploying/).

These include different servers that implement the WSGI specification, such as [Apache/mod_wsgi](http://www.modwsgi.org/) or one of these stand-alone wsgi server http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/deploying/wsgi-standalone/

There are also [uWSGI](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/deploying/uwsgi/) and [FastCGI](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/deploying/fastcgi/) options available

Answer (score 2):

While lightweight and easy to use, Flask’s built-in server is not suitable for production as it doesn’t scale well and by default serves only one request at a time.
http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.12/deploying/