# What is wrong with Bottle's or Flask's built-in HTTP server

Tags: python, performance, security, webserver, bottle

This might be a bit ignorant question, but why everyone is saying [[1](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.11/deploying/),[2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12269537/safe-to-deploy-flask-frameworks-webserver-in-a-production-environment),...] that Flask and/or Bottle HTTP servers are not to be used in production?

Seems like things have changed a lot, for example `bottle+ssl+gevent` sounds like a viable option for production (to me) which handles the main concerns:

- Security (ssl)
- Multiple/parallel requests (gevent)

Am I missing something, like a major security risk? or a performance issue? I mean how much faster might `nginx` or `apache2` be when the major bottleneck is IO?

(Side-question: what you suggest for micro-service deployment with minimal system requirements?)

Cheers

Comment: i believe your answer is already in the 2nd link you provided (the stackoverflow question) concerning flask....i don't know about bottle

Comment: @danidee I see cross-referencing docs. I don't see technical reason other than "It will not handle more than one request at a time by default." / "The development server doesn't scale well." which are addressed nowadays with `gevents`... (I think)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The short answer is that default server is **slow and not concurrent**.
You asked whats wrong with bottle+gevent (leaving aside ssl for now), I don't see anything wrong but **it is not the default server** :)

for small deployment your option seems reasonable but when it will grow bigger and more complex nginx will be a more simple tool to manage since it will separate your concerns (static vs dynamic routing & ssl).

Nginx for example have a much more robust and variable options on ssl handling then the *more* native approach

But as I said, If you are doing a small setup, *keep it simple :)*

Comment: Hey, I was mainly asking about any large performance hit, vulnerabilities and/or known memory leaks. I get that `gevent` is indeed not the default server but is not `apache` or `nginx` setup either. I have a case in my hands where keeping simple (+1) and as system independent as possible is a major plus. Thanks for your answer.