# Python Flask in Production?

Tags: python, web, flask, frameworks, web-development-server

I found a old 2014's post already related to this question, it seems that there is no 2017 answer for this one, could anyone tell me if it changed? I mean, even if the default configuration is not safe, is there a way to suit flask to be production prove?

(old link: [Is the server bundled with Flask safe to use in production?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12269537/is-the-server-bundled-with-flask-safe-to-use-in-production))

I would like to use it, if it scales well and it is safe, I am planning to create something useful. I like this basic easy concept very well, I hope it could be suitable in 2017.

Answer (score 2):

Flask and other Werkzeug servers shouldn't be ran directly. The number one post for the question that you linked to still notes in their  [documentation](http://werkzeug.pocoo.org/docs/0.12/serving/) that it is not safe directly for development.

I use [gunicorn](http://docs.gunicorn.org/en/stable/) for production, it's very easy to use.