# How to serve Flask With Http Server

Tags: python, flask, httpserver

I would like to develop an app that uses both Flask and httpd.
Flask publishes HTML-related files, and httpd publishes files in local files.

It is for browsing local files published in httpd from Flask HTML.

Though the port numbers of Flask and httpd are different, it seems that httpd server side is not working.
Connection refused error occurs when connecting to httpd server.

---

**Added the intention of the question.**

I want to run Flask's built-in web server and HTTPServer simultaneously from a script.
I just want to be able to see myself, not to expose it to the network.

I'm looking for a mechanism that can be completed with the app.py script without using WSGI.

---

**Added additional information to the question.**

This question uses Flask and Python's HTTPServer, but using NodeJS's HTTPServer instead of HTTPServer seems to work well.
(Comment out `run()`)

I would like to complete in Python if possible without using NodeJS HTTPServer.

https://www.npmjs.com/package/http-server

```
C:\Users\User\Videos>http-server
Starting up http-server, serving ./
Available on:
  http://127.0.0.1:8080
Hit CTRL-C to stop the server
...
```

---

version

```
Flask==1.0.2
Python 3.7
```

Can I not start each server with the following code?

templates/index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title></title>
</head>
<body>
  <video src="http://localhost:8080/video.mp4"></video>
</body>
</html>
```

python(app.py)

```
from http.server import SimpleHTTPRequestHandler, HTTPServer

from flask import Flask, render_template

app = Flask(__name__)


@app.route('/')
def hello_world():
    return render_template('index.html')


class Handler(SimpleHTTPRequestHandler):
    def __init__(self, *args, directory=None, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args,
                         directory=r'C:\Users\User\Videos',
                         **kwargs)


def run(server_class=HTTPServer, handler_class=Handler):
    server_address = ('localhost', 8000)
    httpd = server_class(server_address, handler_class)
    httpd.serve_forever()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(host='localhost', port=5000)
    run()
```

It may not have been transmitted well. I'm sorry.
Thank you very much.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Can I not start each server with the following code?

Yes, there are many other ways.

**WSGI**

`wsgi`, which stands for `Web Server Gateway Interface` is defined in [PEP 333](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0333/):

> This document specifies a proposed standard interface between web
>   servers and Python web applications or frameworks, to promote web
>   application portability across a variety of web servers.

**framework side**

`flask`, `django` and many other frameworks all implement this interface. So when you write an app in `flask`, `app` implements `wsgi` so any web server that knows how to serve a `wsgi` app can serve it.

**web server side**

There are many choices and you can find more at [wsgi.org](https://wsgi.readthedocs.io/en/latest/servers.html):

- [gunicorn](https://gunicorn.org/)
- [uWSGI](https://uwsgi-docs.readthedocs.io/en/latest/)
- ...

Basically, you can choose any of these to start your server and use `httpd` to proxy requests to it. Or you can use [mod_wsgi](https://modwsgi.readthedocs.io/en/develop/):

> mod_wsgi is an Apache module that embeds a Python application within
>   the server and allow them to communicate through the Python WSGI
>   interface as defined in the Python PEP 333.

**Note**

The bundled server in `flask` is not suitable for production use, you can see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12269537/is-the-server-bundled-with-flask-safe-to-use-in-production) for more details.

---

**For Updated Question**

> I want to run Flask's built-in web server and HTTPServer
>   simultaneously from a script.

**Just Run Shell Command**

You can start another process and call shell command using [Popen](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.Popen):

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    p = Popen(['python -m http.server'], shell=True)
    app.run(host='localhost', port=5000)
```

Use whatever command you like, you can even start a node http server here.

**Use Thread/Process**

You can start http server in another thread or process, here I use [threading](https://docs.python.org/3/library/threading.html) for example:

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    from threading import Thread
    Thread(target=run, daemon=True).start() 
    app.run(host='localhost', port=5000)
```

**Use Flask To Serve File**

Instead of starting two servers binding to two ports, you can actually use  `flask` to serve file as well. In this way, you only start one server binding to one port:

```
@app.route('/videos/<path:filename>')
def download_file(filename):
    return send_from_directory(r'C:\Users\User\Videos',
                               filename, as_attachment=True)
```

You can see [documentation](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/1.0/api/#flask.send_from_directory) for more details.

Comment: Thank you for the great answer.
But that is different from my desired answer.

Comment: @KKK So you want to make your script work?

Comment: Thank you.
Added the intention of the question.

Comment: @KKK Updated! Hope it can solve your problems.

Answer (score 0):

*app.run()* is a blocking operation. The below lines won't be interpreted.

Run your apps from separate files or in different [thread/process](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/subprocess.html).

Comment: take a look at zappa its brilliant. Run your flask app on aws lambda

Comment: Thank you, I will take a look at zappa