# Is running flask in the default server safe (security-wise)?

Tags: security, flask, localhost

I'm thinking about running a very simple Flask server locally (using the default development server) and then opening it up to the web via http://localhost.run/.  I intend for this to be a personal webhook server and nothing else.

I've seen related questions before (for example, [Is the server bundled with Flask safe to use in production?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12269537/is-the-server-bundled-with-flask-safe-to-use-in-production), etc), but:

1. I don't care that it won't scale well
2. I don't expect to get more than one request at a time
3. I will *not* be using the debugging mode

**My question is this: How safe will my computer and local network be if I do this?**  I will probably limit requests to POST requests and check to see that they have a special key, or something like that, and the only thing I'm going to be *doing* with the webhooks is displaying a notification.

Comment: I ran a flask project from a raspi using the built in development server. Opening up some ports on my local network and so on. Been running it for 2 years, without any known safety issues that I have seen. But yeah, its still risky.. I am doing it knowing it is risky. Anyone with any knowledge can probably get into my network

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Short of someone from the Pallets Project speaking up, the official word on the recommendation is

https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/1.1.x/tutorial/deploy/#run-with-a-production-server

If you have enough access to a server to permit running something that'll listen to a socket, the step of adding a WSGI server isn't a big one. The link above recommends `waitress` (and provides instructions), but `gunicorn` and `uwsgi` will work, too.

Adding my opinion:

Parsing HTTP and dealing with edge-cases is hard, so why should Flask/Werkzeug spend effort dealing with edge cases when there are WSGI front-ends that already take on the responsibility? In their position (which I'm not), I'd punt scaling and security to WSGI servers, and focus on making an excellent framework.

Comment: Ach, and I guess waitress seems so easy, I might as well.