# Using flask for production, but only for background/hidden processes

Tags: python, web-services, flask

So I'm aware flask's development server isn't advised for production for a few reason ([see this question's top answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12269537/is-the-server-bundled-with-flask-safe-to-use-in-production)). However these issues seem to imply either a problem with scalability or security. I have a question related to this  (that may be completely naïve) - give the following setup is there any issue using flask:

1. The webserver itself doesn't run the flask apps, they are stored on a Kubernetes machine that is linked locally.
2. The processes are demanding enough that running more than one concurrently would cause slowdowns, and thus load balancing between Kubernetes is already planned.
3. The user should never be able to directly access the flask apps since they only respond to local addresses (assuming my understanding of how flask set up works).

To my eye this seems to bypass all of the reasons that flask shouldn't be used for deployment - but I still feel like I'm doing something wrong if I go ahead with the above plan. It wasn't designed this way to deal with flask, it just happened to solve all the issues I've read about flask - is there any further dangers than direct user access and scalability and parallelism?

Answer (score 0):

One of the problem I can see a bit above the one you mentionned is software architecture.

When you design a component/software with Flask you should plan for a webserver, may it be [gunicorn](https://gunicorn.org/), [uwsgi](https://uwsgi-docs.readthedocs.io/en/latest/), [cheroot](https://pypi.org/project/cheroot/), etc.

It is not really hard to make one of thoses solution works, and you'll be ready for production and it's easy to change once you have written things to use one. I personnally test locally with cheroot and deploy with gunicorn on cloud platforms.