# python flask to production server

Tags: python, flask

I have made a small API to connect to a database using Flask.

When I run it I get this output on local (which works fine in postman)

```
 * Serving Flask app "main" (lazy loading)
 * Environment: production
   WARNING: This is a development server. Do not use it in a production deployment.
   Use a production WSGI server instead.
 * Debug mode: off
 * Running on http://127.0.0.1:5000/ (Press CTRL+C to quit)
```

I want to run this file (main.py) on a server that I have at 172.22.98.254. But when I run it there it still gives me this output:

```
 * Serving Flask app "main" (lazy loading)
 * Environment: production
   WARNING: This is a development server. Do not use it in a production deployment.
   Use a production WSGI server instead.
 * Debug mode: off
 * Running on http://127.0.0.1:5000/ (Press CTRL+C to quit)
```

So, when I use my postman doing this

[image]

where my post URL is http://172.22.98.254:5000/test, How can I use this from the server that I have. I have an ubuntu server.

Comment: What is an "*ubuntu server*"? Have you read this https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/1.1.x/deploying/? Basically, you should not be running and accessing the Flask app endpoints directly. The `Flask` app instance should be loaded and run by a *separate* production server.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is the server bundled with Flask safe to use in production?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12269537/is-the-server-bundled-with-flask-safe-to-use-in-production)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By default, `app.run()` hosts server on localhost(127.0.0.1). To make it accessible,

```py
app.run('0.0.0.0', port=5000)
```

Although, the server bundled with Flask is not for production, it is recommended to use  WSGI server(mod_wsgi, nginx, gunicorn, etc.)

https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/1.0.x/deploying/wsgi-standalone/

Answer (score 1):

I have changed the host default ip address to server or Local network computer ip address. it works fine. My local ip address is 192.168.1.34, using same port as 5000.

app.run(host='192.168.1.34', port=5000)