# What does it mean by Production Ready Server?

Tags: flask, webserver, gunicorn, flask-socketio

I wanted to get a better understanding of what does it mean for a web-server to be production-ready and ideas about building my web app stack. I am trying to develop server for REST APIs used in my web-app.

Currently, I am using [Flask-SocketIO](https://flask-socketio.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) along with celery in the backend. Celery asynchronously runs heavy tasks on celery and I use web-sockets to emit to the user once the task is complete. I am now planning to put this setup into production. I am aware that native Flask's server is not production-ready as it doesn't scale well ([SO/12269537](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12269537/is-the-server-bundled-with-flask-safe-to-use-in-production)) and should be used with gunicorn/uwsgi/mod_wsgi.

Flask-SocketIO's [documentation](https://flask-socketio.readthedocs.io/en/latest/#deployment) mentions that it is a production-ready server (possibly because it uses gevent/eventlet WSGI server instead of Werkzeug's development server). But it also mentions that these embedded server options can be replaced with gunicorn/uwsgi with some caveats [Flask-SocketIO/issues/#1343](https://github.com/miguelgrinberg/Flask-SocketIO/issues/1343#issuecomment-665940909).

Given these options, I was wondering what are pros-cons of using the default embedded eventlet server instead of gunicorn? How can I know which web-server will work for my use case?

Comment: All the options work. Using eventlet alone or gunicorn+eventlet is a matter of preference.