# flask wsgi file configuration

Tags: python, flask, wsgi

I have created a flask app.I want to run this both development and production server.
This is my app.py file:

```
app = Flask(__name__)

db = SQLAlchemy(app)

app.config.from_object(Config)
db.init_app(app)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run()
```

this is my wsgi.py file:

```
from app import app as application

app = application

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True, host='0.0.0.0', port=5000)
```

I want to know if my wsgi configurtion is ok or is it the right way to do it.How can i make sure my production server will run wsgi.py file with the production database configuration?In local i am getting this warning `Use a production WSGI server instead`.the way i configured willl it ensure it will run on wsgi server in prodcution?While i run this command:

```
uwsgi --wsgi-file app.py --http :5000
```

i am getting internal server error in localhost:5000.

Answer (score 2):

One way of handling this is by having a configuration file (`config.py`) that contains classes for each environment. Then within each of your environments, you'd have a `.env` file that contains environment-specific variables, such as database URIs, secret keys, etc.

Example config file:

```
from os import environ, path
from dotenv import load_dotenv

basedir = path.abspath(path.dirname(__file__))
load_dotenv(path.join(basedir, '.env'))


class Config:
    """Base config."""
    SECRET_KEY = environ.get('SECRET_KEY')
    SESSION_COOKIE_NAME = environ.get('SESSION_COOKIE_NAME')
    STATIC_FOLDER = 'static'
    TEMPLATES_FOLDER = 'templates'


class ProdConfig(Config):
    FLASK_ENV = 'production'
    DEBUG = False
    TESTING = False
    DATABASE_URI = environ.get('PROD_DATABASE_URI')


class DevConfig(Config):
    FLASK_ENV = 'development'
    DEBUG = True
    TESTING = True
    DATABASE_URI = environ.get('DEV_DATABASE_URI')
```

Then, in your application, you can specify which config class you'd like to load.

```
ENV = environ.get("environment")

# Using a production configuration
if ENV=='PROD':
    app.config.from_object('config.ProdConfig')

# Using a development configuration
if ENV=='PROD':
    app.config.from_object('config.DevConfig')
```

For more details, [Flask has some docs on this situation](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.12/config/#configuring-from-files)

Comment: in local i am getting this warning  `Use a production WSGI server instead`.the way i configured willl it ensure it will run on wsgi server in prodcution

Comment: No, the answer above is simply to handle different environment configurations, such as database URIs and environment secrets.

The warning you are seeing regarding the WSGI server is because the wsgi server used by Flask is not meant for production. It does not have all of the controls and capabilities of a production server. If you want to run your app in production, you should use a production-grade wsgi server, such as gunicorn, waitress, or uwsgi. [This answer has more information](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12269537/is-the-server-bundled-with-flask-safe-to-use-in-production)